# A Visual Studio 2008 automated tests project can read a configuration file like app.config? (C# .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, app-config

I have an app.config file inside my TestProject, but when I try to read it using ConfigurationManager it reads from somewhere else and it's none of my app.config's. How to correct this?

Current config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Production" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1,2345;Uid=user;Pwd=password;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_DATA"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Current code:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString
```

Expected output:

```
"Server=127.0.0.1,2345;Uid=user;Pwd=password;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_DATA"
```

Actual output:

```
"data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Referencing it by name.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Production"].ConnectionString
```

The config files automatically integrate machine.config which has that SQLEXPRESS connection string by default.